# How to add a blank List Item when using asp.net filterparameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, filter

A default list item has been added to each dropdown.

When an option is selected from `ddlA` the items in `ddlB` will be filtered.

**PROBLEM**

When using the **ASP.NET** filter parameter the default list item `value=0` will be removed/filtered out from `ddlB`.

**QUESTION**

How can the default list item be kept or re-added to `ddlB` when the list is filtered?

---

**DROPDOWNLIST**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlA" runat="Server" DataSourceID="sqlA" DataTextField="TextA" DataValueField="ValueA" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Select ..." Value="0"/>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlB" runat="Server" DataSourceID="sqlB" DataTextField="TextB" DataValueField="ValueB" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Select ..." Value="0"/>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**DATASOURCE**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlA" runat="Server" SelectCommand="spA" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"/>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlB" runat="Server" SelectCommand="spB" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" FilterExpression="ValueA= '{0}'">
  <FilterParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Col" ControlID="ddlA" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
  </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to have this initial value in your data source so when creating datasource you will need to

```
SELECT 'Select' as TextA, 0 as ValueA
JOIN
Select TextA, ValueA from yourTable
```

these values will be bound to your DropDownLists and stay there 
and one more thing. Remember to remove filter before refiltering

```
SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression=""
```